# Add gradeints to GIMP 2.8 in Ubuntu 12.04 lTS

Tags: gimp

I have added it in Windows 7. Can anyone tell me the path to gradients folder for GIMP in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean gradients window ?

Comment: I have gradients. In Windows I go to program files>gimp>..>gradient.I want to add those .ggr GIMP gradient in Ubuntu as well. Could you guide me please ?

Comment: Solved it finally. Just use ctrl + H on home folder and copy pasted gradients from the folder I had. Thanks @ Dumindu Mahawela and @ Rakesh Godhala, you guys are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to see all the hidden files.

You will see the `.gimp-2.8` folder here. 
Copy your gradient files (`.ggr` extension) to the gradients folder in `.gimp` folder.

Using Terminal:

```
cd /path/to/your/gradient_folder/    
cp * ~/.gimp-2.8/gradients
```

Comment: " cd /Home/Pictures/gradients
bash: cd: /Home/Pictures/gradients: No such file or directory "

Comment: cd Pictures/gradients or cd /home/( username )/Pictues/gradients